# Infinite while loop not waiting for scaning data again in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter no?\n"); // step -1

        if (scanf(" %d", &i) > 0)   // step-2
            printf("Num=%d\n", i);
        else
            printf("Entered character.Pls enter int\n");
    }
}
```

I want to continue the scan again if user entered a value other than integer when I run the above code with a char input it is running infinite loop. Please suggest why or any solution ...?

Comment: Insert a `break`?

Comment: read a character in order to clear it from the top of input?

Comment: `scanf(" %d", &i)` does not consume the " value other than integer".   So it is still where on the next iteration.  And the next, and the next...

Answer (score 0):

If you enter a character say `a` for the above program it will not match with `%d` so it will remain in the buffer. The next time in the loop, it will again not match `%d` and you will enter an infinite loop.

What you can do, is read from the buffer until you encounter a newline character. The second loop will remove any characters until and including the newline character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char dummy;
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter no?\n"); // step -1

        scanf(" %d", &i)
        if (i > 0)   // step-2
            printf("Num=%d\n", i);
        else
            printf("Entered character.Pls enter int\n");

        do{
            scanf("%c",&dummy);
        }while (dummy != '\n');        // Add this loop
    }
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Fixed it. Can you comment on it from the portability aspect.

Comment: 1) `scanf(" %d", &i)` --> `scanf(" %d", &i);` 2) `scanf(" %d", &i)` should check the return value. 3) `if (i > 0)` : OP is not limited to positive numbers. Also Even if input fails, this condition may be met.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter no?\n"); // step -1

        if (scanf_s(" %d", &i) > 0) {   // step-2
            printf("Num=%d\n", i);
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Entered character.Pls enter int\n");
            fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END)` is not reliable (for a related discussion, see http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/230015-does-fseekstdin-0l-seek-end-really-drain-the-input-buffer/).